# How set a (Word/Excel).Document.BeforeCloseEvent (using Interop) to prevent them being closed?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, office-interop

I have a `Windows.Form application` which operates with `Word` and `Excel`. To work with them, I use `Interop package`. Also, I am programming with Visual Studio and C# languaje.

I have created an `EventHandler` which is executed before the Word document is closed and another `EventHandler` which is executed before the Excel document is closed. Function of both events are: Cancel closing document, and hide it instead of closing, so the document continues running in memory.

`ExcelDocument->BeforeCloseEvent` is working fine but the `WordDocument->BeforeCloseEvent` gives the error:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set as an instance
>   of an object.

The line where I get the error is indicated in the follwoing code. (In the code I only show how I include Word/Excel, initiate them, and both EventHandlers... In other part of full code is where I show the applications using aplicacionWord/aplicacionExcel .visible = true,...)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Reflection;
using System.IO;
// Include Word
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
// Include Excel
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

public partial class formWord : Form
{
    // New object type application of Word
    Word.Application aplicacionWord = new Word.Application();
    // New instance for Word document
    Word.Document documentoWord;
    // New object type application of Excel
    Excel.Application aplicacionExcel = new Excel.Application();
    // New instance for Excel document
    Excel.Workbook documentoExcel;
    // New instance for Excel Worksheet
    Excel.Worksheet documentoExcelPrimeraHoja;

    private void formWord_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Word application is not visible
        aplicacionWord.Visible = false;
        // Create new Word document
        documentoWord = aplicacionWord.Documents.Add();
        // Excel application is not visible
        aplicacionExcel.Visible = false;
        // Create new document and get its first worksheet
        documentoExcel = aplicacionExcel.Workbooks.Add(Missing.Value);
        documentoExcelPrimeraHoja = (Excel.Worksheet)documentoExcel.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

        // Word document event before close
        aplicacionWord.DocumentBeforeClose +=
            new Word.ApplicationEvents4_DocumentBeforeCloseEventHandler(
                (Word.Document Doc, ref bool Cancel) => {
                    // If Word aplication is visible, then:
// HERE IS THE ERROR ---------------------------------
// ------- in aplicacionWord --> NULL REFERENCE
                    if (aplicacionWord.Visible)
                    {
                        // Cancel closing document
                        Cancel = true;
                        // Hide againg Word application
                        aplicacionWord.Visible = false;
                    }
                }
            );

        // Excel document event before close
        documentoExcel.BeforeClose +=
            new Excel.WorkbookEvents_BeforeCloseEventHandler(
                (ref bool Cancel) => {
                    // If Excel aplication is visible, then:
                    if (aplicacionExcel.Visible)
                    {
                        // Cancel closing document
                        Cancel = true;
                        // Hide Excel aplication again
                        aplicacionExcel.Visible = false;
                    }
                }
            );
    }
}

// How I close both documents
private void formWord_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{

    // Closing applications
    aplicacionWord.Quit();
    aplicacionWord= null;
    aplicacionExcel.Quit();
    aplicacionExcel = null;
}
```

As I have said, I get no error with Excel's event, but I do in Word's. The Error is due to document's being closed, so... BeforeClose is not working as expected. Is there any other way to work with a BeforeClose event? Or am I doing something wrong?

Also, I do not sure if it is the best way to handle `Document.BeforeCloseEvent` for Word and Excel. Any idea to upgrade this will be great.

Reminder: I want that when a Word/Excel document is closing - the Word/Excel application is visible - (user clicks on `Top-Right-X` to exit) instead of closing the document, hide it so it remains open.

PS: If you want to try the problem on yours machines, you only to change this in my code:

```
// Word application is not visible
aplicacionWord.Visible = true;
// Excel application is not visible
aplicacionExcel.Visible = true;
```

Then, when the c# application is running, close both programs (Word/Excel) and you will see the error.

Comment: The traditional bug in a program like this is code that tries to get the Word process to terminate when the program terminates.  It tends to do stuff like call Marshal.ReleaseComObject().  Always the wrong way to do it, but the interwebs are filled to the brim with bad info about it.  My crystal ball tells me that this code also sets aplicacionWord to null.  Kaboom.  Delete that code, all of it.

Comment: Yes, that's what it looks like, which sets it to NULL. My conclusions are that: First, the BeforeDocumentClose event is not working, since in that case the object should not be set to NULL. Second, if it works, you should not set the object to NULL either, since I am closing a document, not the application. In reference to deleting the code ... I have been explicitly asked to use `interop` ... So I have to do it that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can only speak to Word - but since that's where you're experiencing the error... You say

> Reminder: I want that when a Word/Excel document is closing - the
>   Word/Excel application is visible - (user clicks on Top-Right-X to
>   exit) instead of closing the document, hide it so it remains open.

If the user is clicking on the application's red-x button then he's closing not  the document, but instead he's quitting the Word.Application. That will also close the document which triggers `BeforeClose`, but since the application is no longer available, you get the error - the object `aplicacionWord` is "null".

Word has a `Quit` event, but that gives provides no option to cancel - Word will quit.

You can put code in the `Quit` event, however, to take certain actions, such as set a Boolean you can check in `BeforeClose`, save the document, start a new instance of Word - not visible - and open the document again in the new instance.

It's important to note that in many things Excel and Word are *not* alike. Even though both are under the umbrella "Microsoft Office" they have very different origins and were developed by different teams. There have been occasional attempts to bring all the "core" MS Office apps closer together where they do have things in-common (the Open, Save and Close user interfaces are a prime example), but how they behave "internally" is totally independent and unrelated.